# What can cause bubbling mud?

Tags: landscaping, backyard

https://vimeo.com/326120553

I have a bubbling puddle of mud near my house. It's not my water or sewage lines, I already had the water company come check it out. It doesn't smell like natural gas. What else could it be?

Note that there are two patches, both around the base of the same tree.

There was some rainy weather yesterday, but this is only happening around the base of this one tree.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with home improvement.

Comment: I disagree. I don't know the possible options. For example, could there be an old septic system? How would I know? Could it be a landscape/drainage issue?